# capacitors in FM transmitter circuit

Tags: capacitor

I do not understand use of C1, C4 and C5 in this circuit. I have an idea of purpose of other capacitors but I have no idea about these. Can you explain their purpose and effect on the circuit.

https://www.circuitstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/fm-transmitter-circuit.jpg

[image: https://www.circuitstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/fm-transmitter-circuit.jpg]

Comment: There's millions of FM circuits with good explanations. The picture you've posted doesn't come with any explanation. Find something with a good explanation and read that – it's really no use that we should write the millionth introduction to FM transmitter circuits on the internet.

Comment: generally, websites like circuitstoday.com just copy someone else's circuits and do not do any great own explanation. Sometimes, they even get facts wrong. Usually, they don't understand what they've copied. This schematic is actually a good example, with its BC547 in the RF signal path. You're a student –  you have a great advantage, as you probably have access to a university library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C1 in parallel with the microphone will have two main effects:

1. It will reduce the high-frequency response at high audio frequencies. I'm not sure why that woul dbe desirable in the circuit
2. It will reduce the likelihood of picking up RF interference by the microphone whic could happen if it connected by a cable.

C4 also reduces the response of the circuit to high audio frequencies (although it seems too large for that purpose) C4 also acts as an RF ground for the base of the final oscillator stage.

C5 is to provide positive feedback in the final stage so it acts as an oscillator. L1 and C6 are the main tuning components with the circuit oscillating at the resonant frequency of L1/C6. C6 and the characteristics of the transistor will also affect the oscillating frequency.

The final stage is often referred to as a Colpitts oscillator.

Answer (score -2):

For resonance to occur, thus frequency selectivity to occur, energy must be in a circulating_current path.

These are always series_resonant paths, closed in a loop, otherwise the "circulation" will not occur.

The L1 inductor is important.

How may loops can we find in the circuit, that have L1 included?

There are many, but those with resistors will be highly lossy, and useful energy buildup (and thus frequency selectivity) cannot occur.

The RF transistor has Cob and Cbe junction capacitances. Thus loops may include those.